# Skip a character in range

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression : `/["-,]/`
Which matches a character in range of `:` to `,`
I want to skip the match for `'`(apostrophe).
Any help !!

```
regex.test(strInput);
```

is returning true for a string with an apostrophe.
I need to negate that string which has an apostrophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
/(?!')["-,]/
```

Here `(?!')` is *negative lookahead* which means next character must not be single quote.

Comment: It says me `-` Text range out of order when tested on regex101

Comment: Yes it works for `["-,]` but not for `[:-,]` It think its same as `[c-a]` that is not in range.

Comment: @Braj `:` comes after `,` in the ASCII tables, so you need to invert the order.

Comment: OP wrote regex as `/["-,]/` but mentioned colon in question text so it was confusing.